# Vue js + Element UI [How to print table?]

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I use element io for component. Now my problem is I use this `window.print()` for print but it prints whole page. But I only want to print the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you just need to hide everything

```
@media print{
  *{ display: none; }
  table { display: block; }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Since You are using Vuejs,

You can use "[vue-print-nb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-print-nb)" plugin in vuejs to print specific element on a web page.

Use `v-pript` attribute to print a selected element

**Example**

```
//this is the table you want to print
<table id="myTable">
    ...
    ... //Your table code goes here
</table>

// Set table id to "v-print" attribute.
// This will do the trick.
<button v-print="'#myTable'">Print Table</button>
```

**Note**

You can print the entire page without providing an id to the `v-print` attribute

```
<button v-print>Print the entire page</button>
```